# To make URL for User Profile and products id in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I created the URL in route.php like

`www.domainname/companyname` - Its Work properly

And i also created the URL like

`www.domainname/events` - Its also works good.

But I created the URL like

`www.domainname/category/1` - Its shows error

```
$route["(.*)"] = 'controller/productsname/$1';
$route['Admin'] = 'Admin/login';
$route["category/:num"] = 'controller/category/$1';
$route["(.*)"] = 'controller/productsname/$1';
```

Thanks

Comment: You have duplicated routes. You have to remove first line.

Comment: Don't do this for your products: $route["(.*)"] pick something like domain.com/products/ Much better solution for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but you will probably need to simply point all urls to it, naturally after the rules you've already added.
So something like:

```
$route['Admin'] = 'Admin/login';
$route["category/:num"] = 'controller/category/$1';
$route["(:any)/(:num)"] = 'controller/$1/$2';
//or
$route["(:any)/(:num)"] = 'controller/products/$1/$2';
```